# Partial sums of $e$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$e$ can be calculated as the limit of the partial sums $$\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{i!}$$as $n\rightarrow \infty$. Is it known how to solve this sum to give the numerators in this expression?

That is, does anyone know a way to write$$f(n)=\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{n!}{i!}$$ in a factorised form?

Comment: $e$ is actually obtained by indexing from $i=0$

Comment: If you index from zero this is [A000522](https://oeis.org/A000522) on OEIS.

Comment: @Arthur I meant his $f(n)$.

Comment: @K.defaoite I read denominators of the original sum, sorry.

Comment: There probably isn't a simpler closed formula, but it has a combinatorial meaning - $f(n)$ is the number of ordered proper subsets of a set of $n$ elements.  If you include $i=0,$ as you really should, then you can remove the word "proper."

Comment: The common numerator for the sum to n is n!. but maybe I dont understand your Question ?

Comment: Nobody said anything about "common numerator," a thing which really doesn't exist. @trula The common **denominator** is $n!.$

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I am not a native speaker and got it wrong, of cause I wanted denominator .

Comment: @FShrike thanks I fixed the typo